# I want to change the base path for image of ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I`m making the image upload system on ckeditor with carrierwave.
But when I try to upload the image, it shows an error.

Its because I am running my service on subdirectory '/guide'. so the path to request url is under '/guide'.
So I want to change the base path on ckeditor, but I don`t know how to change...

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRhwm.png)

I want to change the request url from this

//localhost:3000/ckeditor/pictures?&CKEditor=post_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ja

to

//localhost:3000/guide/ckeditor/pictures?&CKEditor=post_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ja

Comment: You have to customize base path setting. Please refer this doc. https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails#include-customized-ckeditor_basepath-setting

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I added basepath.js.erb. 
<%
  base_path = ''
  base_path << "/#{Rails.root.basename.to_s}/" if ENV['PROJECT'] =~ /editor/i
  base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
  base_path << '/ckeditor/'
%>

var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/guide<%= base_path %>';
But it`s not changing.